# Magento 2 ui component form checkbox pre-checked. Checked as default

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

Hi I'm stucked on a simple checkbox. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a custom checkbox checked as default. Basically, I created a custom field on the Checkout Page.

```
<item name="ship_when_complete" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                  <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                  <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                  <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                 </item>
                 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.ship_when_complete</item>
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
```

Does not seem to work even if I put

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="boolean">1</item>
```

or

```
<item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Valuemap does not work as well.
I also created custom template but the value won't capture.

Please let me know how to overcome this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer im looking:

```
<item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
<item name="valueUpdate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Complete xml code

```
<item name="ship_when_complete" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                  <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                  <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                  <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                  <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                  <item name="valueUpdate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 </item>
                 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.ship_when_complete</item>
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for two thing

1. data-bind="checked: isChecked" is implement or not
2. check in your js Compoment js defaults have `isChecked: ko.observeable(true);`

and then in `<item name="config" xsi:type="array"> add <item name="isChecked" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

Happy Coding

Comment: Hi doesnt seem to work. I have sample js

Comment: Hi Nilesh it is now checked as default but won't change the database value. Database still shows false. How can it manipulate the value and insert to db?

Comment: Using this code now checked as default? If yes happy to know that. Second, your data is not saving to the database right and I assume you have created the column in order table  if that is also yes then you need to use an observer to set that something like this $order->setData('my_checkbox', $checkboxValue);

Comment: Im following this module: https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form but could not make checkbox work

Comment: That's why I had mentioned that you have to use observer after order placed to save you value into database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set the default checkbox value in ui_component

```
<item name="ship_when_complete" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
        <item name="default" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="true" xsi:type="number">false</item>
            <item name="false" xsi:type="number">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.ship_when_complete</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
</item>
```

Let me know if you have any other issue with the code Thanks

Comment: Hi I'm trying to implement this code https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form with additional checkbox. Checkbox with checked as default